# Function in an external file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling to understand why the function that I defined in the external JS file doesn't print anything on the page:

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src = "script.js">
        start(document);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my JS file:

```
function start(doc) {
    doc.writeln("<h1>Hello from JS</h1>");
    return;
}
```

I expect this function to do a standard hello-world output but I see only an empty screen.

UPD: both files are in the same folder

Comment: A script tag can't have a `src` attribute and a body at the same time.  The body will be ignored and the script specified by `src` is loaded.

Comment: Do you have a js debugger such as firebug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Amy mentioned, you can't use both a `src` attribute **and** contained JS. Anything inside the body of the tag will be ignored.

Create a separate `<script>` tag to contain your call:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>start(document);</script>
```

**HTML** [Script](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) tag.